# How to play MediaPlayer sound after a few seconds?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've got:

```
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.aurabroly);
    player.setLooping(false);
    player.setVolume(100,100);
    player.start();
```

How do I make play it after 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

```
   player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.aurabroly);
   player.setLooping(false);
   player.setVolume(100,100);

   CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(6000,1000) {

              @Override
              public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onFinish() {
                 player.start();
              }
    };
    timer.start();
```

use count down timer to give delay of 5 seconds or you can use handler postdelayed

Answer (score 0):

For instance:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(YourActivity.this, R.raw.aurabroly);
            player.setLooping(false);
            player.setVolume(100, 100);
            player.start();
        }
    }, 5000);
```

But keep in mind that in 5 seconds situation can changed, for example your activity get destroyed, so you need to check it before play sound.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a `Handler` with the `postDelayed` method.

e.g.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // to run after 5 sec
    }
}, 5 * 1000);
```